# Attribute value expected (Android Studio)

Tags: android

what i wanna do is when they click the Rate button it brings up the 5 stars for them to rate but i am getting this Attribute value expected error.

need 10 rep to post images so imma just give link to image.

Error : http://prntscr.com/7iiy1k

...what i really want is a personal helper. Teamviewer or share screen on skype and help me out with this... i just need a boost. i am experienced with Visual Studio just need help with Android Studio.

Thank you.

Comment: Copy the text in your question, don't use images.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you messed up your layout and visibility atrtibute is wrongly formatted. Change it to

```
android:visibility="VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, or GONE."
```

Not sure if you also need to add `onClick` since it's part of the mess

```
android:onClick="YourFunction"
```

Comment: yea figured the visible part out right after i made the post...but i deleted them post and made another pic. cause i still have the error but got rid of one.

Comment: Click enter after `"visible"`. Attribute `onClick` should be on the next line

Comment: i feel foolish lol thank you very much. Been awhile... am i asking for too much when i ask for a partner from here? i asked all my skype friends and none have experience doing this for some reason... is this very similer to visual studio?

Comment: I'm afraid you probably won't have luck asking for a skype partner, that's not what this site is for. And yes, it's totally different to visual studio.

Comment: ok and can i ask.. when i hit run.. it brings up an android, an emulator and the screen is just black on the phone. eventually an android logo appears but just stays on that logo. how do i test my app without exporting it and putting it on my phone. sorry im literally new to this ha